# When do I hyphenate compound nouns used as adjectives?

Tags: style, orthography, compound-nouns

For example, is the correct phrase English-language journals or English language journals?

Comment: This is probably more a matter of style and context than hard-and-fast rules - the hyphen in your example 'ties' the word 'language' to 'English', but could be used to 'tie'  the word 'language' to the word 'journals' if that was necessary/appropriate.

Comment: Mostly with things like: gun-toting fools//banana-eating donkeys. etc/

Answer (score 2):

There isn't always a hard and fast rule surrounding each compound noun in question - some can be written several ways, for example, "*bus-stop*" can be written "*bus stop*".

However, you *should* ideally use a hyphen when using a compound noun as an attributive noun - in other words, using a noun as an adjective. This is to eliminate any confusion as to which words are joined.

Take your example of "English language journals". Is the word 'language' joined to *English*, or to *journals*?

- An **English-language journal** would be a journal *in* or possibly *about* the English language.
- An **English language-journal** would be a journal about language in general, that just happens to be written in English, or arguably even from England.

Your example is the former - you want to use *English-language* as a compound attribute noun for the *journals*, so the hyphen ideally should be used.

Another example would be "dry-cleaning shop", a shop that does dry-cleaning. Without the hyphen, it could be a cleaning shop that isn't wet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question, however, is about journals that are in English, not about the language. Would “English language journals” be acceptable, or should I write “English-language journals”?

Comment: @Laurie I mentioned in my answer that "English-language journal" could also be a journal *in* English. Thinking about it further, I actually think that would be the first assumption, rather than a journal about language. The wider context would no doubt make that clear anyway. I've adjusted my answer slightly, go with "English-language journals".

Comment: I don't think many would juxtapose your two journal examples. And English language-journal just strikes me as wrong.